# Initializing an array with a trailing '\0'

Tags: c

I find myself doing the following quite a bit:

```
char vals[count+1];
vals[count] = '\0';
```

Is there a simpler way to do this initialization where the array goes to:

```
{..., 0}
```

Comment: Define "simpler"? That looks pretty basic as it is. You could init the whole array to 0 but not sure if you consider that "simpler". `char vals[count+1] = {0};`

Comment: @kaylum sure that works. I have a VLA which I want to fill with a string that is of `count` length. Would the more common way to initialize that be what you suggest above? Want to post an answer with the suggested way and I can accept that?

Comment: If you want to copy a null-terminated string where you additionally know the length, uses `memcpy()`.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you're trying to do. If you're trying to represent a string whose printable length could be anything from `0` to `count`, then perhaps it'd make sense to init it all to zeros and just overwrite characters from left to right as necessary. But if you know its length will be exactly `count`, then there's no reason to waste time initializing a bunch of zeros when you'll just overwrite them immediately afterwards. In that case, the way you're doing it is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization shows you can do something like `int a[MAX+1] = {[MAX]=0}` but my compiler doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: @carl.hiass it will not work if MAX is not a constant expression

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I see, thanks for pointing that out. So I could do something like `#define max2 5` `char vals[max2+1] = {[max2]=0};`, but it wouldn't work on a VLA where I have a variable length input, correct?

Comment: @carl.hiass yes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro, "simplifying" those things:

```
#define CHAR_ARR(SIZE, NAME) char NAME[(SIZE) + 1]; NAME[SIZE] = '\0'
```

or as alternative, initialize the whole array to 0

```
char arr[size + 1] = { 0 }; // mind the possible performance impact here
```

however, i would highly recommend to not do this, as the correct way to end a C-String is to end it with a `\0` and not the array containing it.

At best, you build your logic to automatically supply the terminating `\0` instead of initializing your buffers, writing out the `\0` and hoping that it is never overriden by accident or an off-by-one issue.
Doing it manually generally is only really ever needed when you are in doubt that it got set by the filling method (eg. `strncpy` with a smaller buffer than required for the input string).

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland wouldn't it work inside a function though? https://godbolt.org/z/r3Ev5P

Comment: it is advertised as an universal solution.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland oh, got it.

Comment: I am not sure where your "point" is relevant. It should be obvious to anyone, programming C that you need a function scope to actually execute code.

Comment: that is a "minor mistake" (mostly coding convention) you could have easily pointed out instead of invalidating the answer, which is correct.

Comment: it is a very "major" mistake not the coding convention

Comment: Feel free to provide proof to your point of it being a major mistake.

Comment: i am well aware of that @AndreasWenzel but still thanks again for the hint. I did not feel it was necessary here.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland The example you provided is not relevant to the actual question provided or the answer i provided here.

Comment: Generally this kind of macros with more than one statement inside **must not** be written the way you did.

Comment: The question asked about a way to simplify that part of OPs code further, to which i provided a solution and pointed out that one should not do it, not arguing about my answer to OPs question but why the approach to attempt to simplify this is wrong. The macro itself also is not relevant to what you linked, given that in the case of `if (...) CHAR_ARR(5, arr) else ...` or any other similar code would make no sense, given that `arr` immediatly would leave the scope.  A different solution for this macro (like `do { ... } while (0);` as content is also not possible for the same reason.